# If app is compiled only for armv7 and armv7s, what size data types does it use when running on an arm64 device?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c, xcode

I have set the "Architectures" setting in Xcode to armv7, armv7s.

What happens when I run my app on an arm64 device like the iPhone5s.

Will the size of `long` be 64bit or 32bit ?

Comment: Did my answer help? Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I don't know how to verify if it is correct, since I don't have an arm64 device.

Comment: If you could verify it yourself, the you wouldn't have to ask :-) So how can I convince you? You could build a OS X app in 32-bit mode and run it on your Mac (which has a 64-bit processor).

Comment: Good idea. On my mac long is 4bytes in 32bit mode, and 8 bytes in 64bit mode. my mac is 64bit. I assume it would work the same way in iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *compiler* creates 32-bit or 64-bit code, depending on the selected architecture.

Therefore, if the app is compiled for a 32-bit architecture (like armv7, armv7s), 
the size of `long` is 32-bit, regardless of the actual device that the code is
running on.